# How to add an explanatory text before a list view in android?

Tags: android, xml, listview, text

I have a list view but at the begining i want to place a piece of text that will help the users to understand what't the purpose of that list. After that i want to display the list and i want to be srollable. The scroll i know how to do it, but the text part no. I've tryed to make two layouts, one for the text and another for the list, but my xml instantly becomes fill with errors.

That's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/legislatie1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textSize="10pt" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: place a textview above the listview. update the text for textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static TextView above the ListView if you choose, but it will not scroll with the ListView.  An alternative is to add a Header to your ListView, which will scroll with the list.  [Header Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter)